# Styling MUI components in React with CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, tsx

I want to style all the `<Chip>` inside the `<Grid>` that has the class `.table-header` but they does not change ther style (i put a `<p>` that should be colored in red and it works).
Why it works for the `<p>` and not for the `<Chip>`? I want to do this without putting the same class in each `<Chip>`.

I am using MUI v5.11.4

portion of tsx code:

```js
<Grid className={classes['table-header']}>
  <Grid item xs={1} />
  <Grid item xs={2}>
    <Chip avatar={<Avatar>1</Avatar>} label="Element1" />
    <p>Red text</p>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={4}>
    <Chip avatar={<Avatar>2</Avatar>} label="Element2" />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={5} />
</Grid>
```

module.css code:

```
.table-header Chip {
  width: 100%;
}

.table-header p {
  color: red;
}
```

[CODE SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-lederberg-fwchos?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Can you send codesandbox link?

Comment: Added in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your selectors in the right way. Here how you can set the styled component for the `Chip`:

```
// import styled components
import { styled } from "@mui/system";

// Create the styled component for the Chip
  const StyledChip = styled(Chip)({
    "& .MuiChip-label": {
      color: "red"
    }
  });

// Use it like this example:
<StyledChip avatar={<Avatar>1</Avatar>} label="Element1" />
```

Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-thunder-rwlp7o?file=/demo.js) with your solution.

**UPDATE:**
Based on your comment that you don't want to use styled component, I was able to do it like this:

```
.table-header :global .MuiChip-label {
  color: red;
}
```

You need to mark the `.MuiChip-label` class as `:global`

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-frost-0pxtkp?file=/src/styles.module.css) with the second solution

Comment: I can not use the styled component, there is a way to do it using only the parent class from the `module.CSS` file?

Comment: @Riccardo, i have updated my code based on your latest comment, and added the codesandbox forked from your repo.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was searching for!